# LM317 Constant Current Battery Charger Question

Tags: constant-current, lm317

LM317 constant current charger are quite popular as it seems. I made one for my 12v 7Ah Lead Acid battery. I used  a 2.2 ohm 10 watt resistor and calculated that it would give a decent amount of constant current to charge my battery. To my surprise, I noticed that the battery is drawing only 20 - 30mA current when charging. Currently the battery is little over-discharged to 11.8v.

I had an impression that LM317 Constant current mode pumps constant amount of current, no matter what the load is. Was my understanding wrong?
If so, should the constant current value, i.e 1.25/R is actually the max current value? Because when I sorted the output terminals of the power supply, it reached upto desired current level, i.e (1.25/2.2) * 1000 mA

And if my understanding of LM317  constant current supply is correct, why is the  battery drawing only 20mA  current?

My circuit is as simple as following.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmruwl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please provide a schematic diagram that shows the exact circuit you created.

Comment: Let me guess. You are using a voltage source of something like 12 volts, with an LM317  current source, right? Your problem is that the LM317 itself should have at least 2 volts across it, plus another 1.25 across the current set resistor. Since 12-volt SLAs will charge to about 13.5 volts, you need a voltage source of at least 17 to 18 volts. 20 would be better.

Comment: What is the charger's output voltage during the CC charging phase (with the charger attached to the battery)? Also, measure with a DMM and report back to us the LM317's unregulated input voltage (the "15V input voltage") when the battery charger circuit is connected to and charging the battery.

Comment: Charging a 7ah battery is really beyond the capabilities of an LM317 unless you figure a way to use an external pass transistor to dissipate all the heat. Honestly you would be better off using an op-amp to control a power FET or BJT.

Comment: I measured the open corcuit Input and Output voltage across the regulator. It was 15.2v and 14v respectively.

Comment: mkeith Thanks for responding. I am not looking for a working charger circuit in particular. I am more interested to learn how LM317 constant current mode behaves.

Comment: Can you please show your actual circuit? The LM317 is probably in dropout. Or it has over-heated and triggered the thermal protection. For the most part, that is the problem with the LM317. If you give it enough input voltage to stay in regulation, it is probably going to get too hot unless you are using it as a reference. But if you just want a reference, use a TL431.

Comment: Added the circuit

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Line regulation for the [TI LM317](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) indicates that it could require 3 V headroom to operate properly.*

The LM317 has a relatively high dropout voltage compared with modern LDO (low drop-out) regulators. Add to this the 1.25 V across the current sense resistor and you can see that your supply voltage is too low.

The big question is why you are charging lead acid batteries using constant current. You should be using constant voltage.

---

From the datasheet:

**9.3.8 50-mA Constant-Current Battery-Charger Circuit**

The current limit operation mode can be used to trickle charge a battery
at a fixed current.
\$ I_{CHG} = 1.25V ÷ 24Ω \$. 
\$ V_I \$ should be greater than \$ V_{BAT} + 4.25 V \$. (1.25V [\$ V_{REF} \$]+
3V [headroom]).

Comment: Well, the first stage is usually constant current until a specific Voltage target is reached. Then hold that Voltage (stage 2) then drop to a long-term float Voltage (stage 3).

Comment: As mkeith said, I learned first constant current charging then constant voltage for float voltage. Did I learn wrong? Sorry, I am new in Electronics!

Comment: Yes my question gets a classic example here. See the contradicting facts in the LM317 Datasheet shared by @Transistor

Comment: See sections "9.3.3 Precision Current-Limiter Circuit" and 
"9.3.8 50-mA Constant-Current Battery-Charger Circuit". At first section the I is referred as I Limit, seems like the max limit of I which can be drawn of the circuit. It never says I would remain constant with any load.
But in the next section, it is said that the circuit is a 50mA constant current charger. How come the same circuit is used to get constant current (I am assuming that I use a fixed value resistor for both cases, no POT).

Comment: There are no contradicting facts in the datasheet. (The LM317 is more than 40 years old so they know what they're talking about.) Section 9.3.8 clearly shows that you need 4.25 V more on the input than you want on the output. See my update.

Comment: Hi @Transistor I didn't mean to say they were wrong. I just wanted to get an understanding why the 2 sections seem contradicting? Which of my understanding is wrong?

I understand the 4.25V factor. But what is the Iout exactly? Is it Imax, or Iconst? I mean, should the output current remain constantly as calculated with formula 1.2/R, or is it the short circuit (max) current limit and eventually falls with large resistance load? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: The output will rise as it tries to get 1.25 V between the output and the ref. pin. If charging a battery you will get constant 50 mA until the voltage of the battery gets within 4.25 V of Vin. At that stage the regulation will start to fail.

Comment: Oook. Now I understand what it means. Thanks for clarifying Transistor.

Comment: The condition where the linear regulator is trying to maintain the correct output voltage, but the input voltage is too low, that condition is called "dropout." A low-dropout (LDO) regulator is one where Vout can be correct even when Vin is only a little bit higher than Vout. The LM317 is NOT an LDO.